# how to solve file permission error in installing cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, directory, permissions, cocoapods

When I uninstall cocoapods I get this message

```
Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
```

and when I write this command 
sudo gem install cocoapods
I get this error

```
While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

Comment: try 'sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin'